# Is there any way to prevent users dragging a link to desktop and create a shortcurt?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

My program is a web based windows app. I found I can drag the links in app to desktop and the system will create a shortcut that will expose my true url, and some bad UE.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: You can prevent the drag, but it won't stop users from accessing the URL. Fix the problem, don't just hide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be the solution you're looking for:

```
document.getElementById('notClickable').ondragstart = function() { return false; };
```

Please let me know if it worked!

Comment: No problem, I actually found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205940/disable-anchor-link-click-drag-in-html-page-swipe-a-container-with-links-ins  Might be interesting ;)